# How to replace a DataBase Table by a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, sql-server-ce

I am trying to replace a Table (FooTable) in my DataSource (an **SQL CE** Database) by a `DataTable` (which bind to a `DataGrid`). The reason I want to do this is: after I populate from a Database to a `DataSet` (which show all the rows on the `DataGrid`), I might edit, delete, and add multiple rows to the `DataTable`. Instead of updating my changes to DataSource (`SQL CE`) each time I modified the DataTable, I want to do it collectively at the end of the session.

My approach is straight-forward:

1. `DELETE` all data from my DataSource table (FooTable) (I'm using **SQL CE**, so `TRUNCATE` is not available)
2. INSERT the `DataTable's` data in to the emptied DataSource Table

Following is my C# code

```
/* Truncate the DataSource Table */
SqlCeCommand delCmd = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM FooTable", conn)
conn.Open();
delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

/* Insert DataTable into an empty DataSource Table */
string ins = @"INSERT INTO FooTable (FooName) values (@fooName)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(ins, conn);
da.InsertCommand = cmd;
da.Update(ds, "FooTable");
```

The codes work if I add or delete rows on the `DataTable`, but when I edit a specific row on the `DataTable` and Insert the table to my DataSource, I get the following error

**"Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."**

I do not understand why I get this error. I have already empty all rows in my DataSource table and my DataSource shouldn't not know there are modified rows but insert all DataTable Rows as new rows.

Or, is there a simple way to "REPLACE" a DataSource table by a DataTable?

**[EDITED]**

I tried setting the RowState manually like below code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   row.RowState = DataRowState.Added;
}
```

but RowState is only read only and cannot be written.

**[EDITED - 2nd]**
I tried setting it using SetAdded()

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   row.SetAdded();
}
```

Then I get the following error:
"**SetAdded and SetModified can only be called on DataRows with Unchanged DataRowState.**"

Still not manage to get it to work...

**[EDITED - 3rd]**
So finally get it to work with the following code:

```
using (SqlCeCommand insCmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO FooTable (FooName) VALUES (@fooName)", conn))
{
    insCmd.Parameters.Add("@fooName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "FooName");

    dt.AcceptChanges();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        row.SetAdded();
    }

    da.InsertCommand = insCmd;
    da.Update(ds, "FooTable");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataTable` tracks `RowState`s internally.
When you modify an existing row, its `RowState` becomes `Modified`, so the `DataAdapter` tries to run an `UPDATE` command.

You need to call the `SetAdded()` method on the modified rows to set their `RowState`s to `Added` rather than `Modified`.

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried to modified the RowState to RowState.Added, but RowState is read only and does not let me to change manually (see edited code)..

Comment: @KMC: Call the `SetAdded()` method.

Comment: thanks for the follow, but I did as you said, and it gives me this error "SetAdded and SetModified can only be called on DataRows with Unchanged DataRowState."... I edited my question.

Comment: @KMC: Call `table.AcceptChanges()` first.